# DSE Cassandra SSL Handshake Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found

Tags: cassandra

I am getting below exception :

```
ERROR [MessagingService-Outgoing-/10.16.252.241-Gossip] 2020-05-15 08:39:10,957  OutboundTcpConnection.java:597 - SSL handshake error for outbound connection to 7abffb17[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=/10.16.252.241,port=7001,localport=52222]]
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
```

I am adding self-signed certificate. I have added to certificate to cacerts in java security path, But still it not working.

Comment: please follow procedures described here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.7/security/secSslTOC.html - they were recently tested by multiple people

Comment: I have followed all the steps

Comment: `cacerts` is for enabling SSL with Java apps.  You need to add your cert to _both_ truststore and keystore files.  They also need to be specified in the appropriate sections of the `cassandra.yaml`.

Comment: ok...i have added the certificate to both truststore and keystore, still getting exception.

Comment: along with the above exception, getting below exception

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Certificate signature validation failed

Comment: @Pushpa Were you able to find a solution for this? I am facing the same error.